# Problema PHP Warning: Undefined array key "shipping_country" in ... /wp-content/plugins/wc-apg-nifcifnie-field/includes/clases/pedido.php on line 328

Tags: php, array, undefined

soy super novato en esto del PHP, pero si conozco otros lenguajes de programación y estoy intentado descifrar por que obtengo el error que indico en el titulo y que vuelvo a indicar aquí con toda la url completa:

PHP Warning:  Undefined array key "shipping_country" in /home/peaceofm/public_html/wp-content/plugins/wc-apg-nifcifnie-field/includes/clases/pedido.php on line 328

Hace referencia al plugin que utilizo para obtener el NIF/NIE/CIF en el formulario de pedido de web siguiente:

**WC – APG NIF/CIF/NIE Field**

https://wordpress.org/plugins/wc-apg-nifcifnie-field/

Detalles sobre el plugin:

Pese a que está configurado para que el NIF/NIE/CIF sea un campo requerido para poder finalizar el pedido, de un tiempo a esta parte a dejado de funcionar correctamente y en algunos casos se realizan pedidos sin cumplimentar el NIF.

Como nosotros no hacemos ventas físicas, la dirección de envío está desactivada para los pedidos, por tanto el cliente ni si quiera ve el formulario de "Envío" y el plugin está configurado para que omita la información de envío.

Misterio por resolver:

Si el plugin está debidamente configurado para que omita la información de envío... ¿Por qué genera el dichoso error de PHP Warning en el campo "shipping_country"?

El fallo lo indica en la línea 328 del código del archivo pedido.php que os pego aquí:

[image: error-php]

Comment: contacta el dev del plugin para que le ponga un default o guard al if onda `if ('ES'==($_POST['shipping_country'] ?? 'lol') ...`. el plugin asume que hay un valor enviado por POST con nombre `shipping_country` el `??'lol' ` le define un default

Comment: Hola Alo, gracias por tu rápida respuesta...

Hay posibilidad de insertar algún código en el functions de mi child theme para solucionarlo?

Lo comento por que es un plugin gratuito y los desarrolladores lo tienen como cebo para muchos otros que si cobran... con lo cual, no lo actualizan con frecuencia y por lo que he visto en su página, como que pasan bastante de dar soporte.

Aunque sea algo provisional y efímero (cuando actualicen el plugin) por favor, ¿Me puedes indicar cual sería el código **exacto** que debería de incluir en mi archivo pedido.php.?

Muchas gracias amigo!!

Comment: yo te recomiendo hacer el [tour] para que comprendas en que onda va el sitio ...

Answer (score 1):

increible pero cierto!

Me han contactado desde el soporte del plugin y me han comentado que para la próxima actualización tendrán en cuenta el bug e implementaran el código que me han facilitado para modificar la línea 328 del archivo pedido.php para que la modifique yo mismo:

```
if ( isset( $_POST[ 'shipping_country' ] ) && $_POST[ 'shipping_country' ] == "ES" && isset( $_POST[ 'shipping_nif' ] ) ) {
```

Saludos a todos!!